# Exceptions vs Errors in Python

Tags: python, exception

I come from Java where Exceptions and Errors are quite different things and they both derive from something called `Throwable`.
In Java normally you should never try to catch an Error.

In Python though it seems the distinction is blurred.

So far after reading some docs and checking [the hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) I have the following questions:

1. There are syntax errors which of course cause your program not to be able to start at all. Right?
2. "Errors detected during execution are called *exceptions* and are not unconditionally fatal" (per [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions)). What does "fatal" mean here? Also, some objects like `AttributeError` are (by the above definition) actually exceptions even though they contain Error in their names, is that conclusion correct?
3. Some classes derive from `Exception` but contain Error in their name. Isn't this confusing? But even so it means that Error in the name is in no way special, it's still an Exception. Or not... ?
4. "All built-in, non-system-exiting exceptions are derived from [Exception]" (quote from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.Exception))
   So which ones are **system-exiting** exceptions and which ones are not? It is not immediately clear. All user-defined exceptions should also be derived from  Exception. So basically as a beginner do I need to worry about anything else but Exception? Seems like not.
5. Warnings also derive from Exception. So are warnings fatal or system-exiting or none of these?
6. Where does the `AssertionError` fit into all of this? Is it fatal or system exiting?
7. How does one know or specify that some Exception class represents fatal or system-exiting exception?

Comment: Correct, for your purposes there are just Exceptions.

Comment: Not sure how these things differ in Java, but in PHP "errors" are basically just something that produces an error message on screen/in the log, while exceptions are something which can be hierarchically handled via `try..catch`. In that sense, Python doesn't make that distinction. Every possible error is an exception and can be handled via `try..except`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1. Yes. `SyntaxError` isn't catchable except in cases of dynamically executed code (via `eval`/`exec`), because it occurs before the code is actually running.
2. "Fatal" means "program dies regardless of what the code says"; that doesn't happen with exceptions in Python, they're all catchable. `os._exit` can forcibly kill the process, but it does so by bypassing the exception mechanism.
3. There is no difference between exceptions and errors, so the nomenclature doesn't matter.
4. System-exiting exceptions derive from `BaseException`, but not `Exception`. But they can be caught just like any other exception
5. Warnings behave differently based on the warnings filter, and deriving from `Exception` means they're not in the "system-exiting" category
6. `AssertionError` is just another `Exception` child class, so it's not "system exiting". It's just tied to the `assert` statement, which has special semantics.
7. Things deriving from `BaseException` but not `Exception` (e.g. `SystemExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt`) are "not reasonable to catch" (or if you do catch them, it should almost always be to log/perform cleanup and rethrow them), everything else (derived from `Exception` as well) is "conditionally reasonable to catch". There is no other distinction.

To be clear, "system-exiting" is just a way of saying "things which `except Exception:` won't catch"; if no `except` blocks are involved, all exceptions (aside from warnings, which as noted, behave differently based on the warnings filter) are "system-exiting".

Comment: Your answer is very good (the best on this page), and I've been rereading it multiple times. And still... this whole thing looks like a complete mess (compared to the situation in other languages). Messy hierarchy, messy terminology. It's all for historical reasons, I suppose. No base `Error` class even. Then some things called Errors which derive from Exception. Just weird. I know you can't do anything about it, I am leaving this comment here for other newcomers (to Python).

Comment: @peter.petrov: I think the main thing to keep in mind is that there is no separate category for "error". "Error" and "exception" are synonymous in Python. Aside from that, there's just looking at the [exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) so you know which classes derive from `BaseException` without deriving from `Exception`, and remembering to never use bare `except:` (which would catch the `BaseException` stuff too).

Comment: I agree the hierarchy is a little off; `MemoryError` should not have fallen under `Exception` (there are rare cases where you want to catch it, but even when you do, you should be catching it specifically, same as `KeyboardInterrupt`, not catching it by accident with `except Exception:` that probably wasn't written to handle out of memory conditions). Similarly, `OverflowError`, intended for arithmetic that exceeds representation limits, is actually used primarily for "passed Python `int` too large to convert to C register width type"; it's not an `ArithmeticError` (the parent class) at all.

Comment: But most of the rest of it makes sense. It may not agree with more rigid nomenclature from languages that make distinctions between uncatchable terminal errors and catchable runtime exceptions, but that's because Python ensures nothing (aside from intentional `os._exit` calls or bugs that segfault the interpreter) is terminal ("We're all adults here" means if you really want to catch something you shouldn't, they'll let you). Python is simpler, which ends up being confusing to people expecting/used to a greater complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions are designed for the programmer to know how to handle them such as outOfRange
Once an exception arises the programmer has to decide how to handle it and the code can continue to operate relatively smoothly

On the other hand an error indicates a problem that the programmer could not foresee as an import error or a memory error
Errors can still be addressed and ensure that the software continues to run but apparently not everything will be able to continue to work smoothly.